# 5 dropdowns having same value initially and if update anyone of them then it will update other dropdown. remove that selceted one from others

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am having 5 drop down having same value.

```
<select name='a' class='test'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
</select>

<select name='b' class='test'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
</select>

<select name='c' class='test'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
</select>

<select name='d' class='test'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
</select>

<select name='e' class='test'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
</select>
```

If I select one of them then it should remove that  selected one from other drop downs.
And if I change anyone of them it will remove that one from other drop downs and it should add that unselected in others drop down?

How can we use this?
Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Just to prove that you're just not fishing for others to do work for you..

Answer (score 0):

Try this use jQuery

```
$("select").change(function(){
  var selected = $(this).val();
  $("[value="+$(this).val()+"]").removeAttr("selected");
  $(this).find("[value="+selected+"]").attr("selected","selected");
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tqrhpw9c/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.test').change(function() {
      var selectedOption = $(this).val();
      $('.test option[value="' + selectedOption + '"').removeAttr('selected');
      $(this).val(selectedOption);
    });
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZTAZvNEy5Y0PwlVPkqHU?p=preview

Comment: it is resetting the value if that is already selected. so it will not work for me.

Comment: You requested this: "If I select one of them then it should remove that selected one from other drop downs."

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var previousVal;
var previousText;
$('select.test').focus(function () {

  previousVal = $(this).val();
  previousText = $(this).find("option[value='" + previousVal + "']").text();
});
$('select.test').change(function () {

  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  var option = $("<option>");
  option.attr("value", previousVal);
  option.text(previousText);
  if (previousVal != 0) {
    $("select.test[name !='" + name + "']").append(option);
  }
  if ($(this).val() != 0) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("select.test[name !='" + name + "']").find("option").filter(function() {

      return $(this).attr("value") == value;
    }).remove();
  }
});
```

Tested it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6tghbzx0/1/)